# How to return promise from fs.unlink

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

I want to delete a file and wait for the deletion to succeed before moving forward. I have used unlink function inside a promise to get the result, but when unlink done successfully then I am getting the result from the promise if there is any kink of error while deleting the file the promise does not return any error.

Service:

```
public removeUserImage(
   user: User,
): Promise<NodeJS.ErrnoException | boolean> {
   const pathToRemoveImage = 'src/public/uploads'+ '/' + user.image_url;

   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       unlink(pathToRemoveImage, (error) => {
          if (error) reject(error);
          resolve(true);
       });
    });
 }
```

Controller:

```
const isFileRemoved = await this._userService.removeUserImage(user);

//This block not excuting
if (!isFileRemoved) {
    throw new InternalServerErrorException(
        'Error occurred while trying to remove file.',
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your promise *rejects* if there's an error. When using `await`, you need to wrap the code in `try..catch` in order to handle any failures

```ts
try {
  await this._userService.removeUserImage(user);
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err);
  throw new InternalServerErrorException(
    'Error occurred while trying to remove file.'
  );
}
```

FYI, you can (and should) use the [Promises API](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#promises-api) versions of the `fs` functions

```ts
import { unlink } from "node:fs/promises";

public removeUserImage({ image_url }: User): Promise<void> {
  const pathToRemoveImage = `src/public/uploads/${image_url}`;

  return unlink(pathToRemoveImage);
}
```

---

If you wanted your method to always *resolve* with a Boolean, you'd want something like

```ts
return unlink(pathToRemoveImage)
  .then(() => true) // resolve with "true" for success
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error("removeUserImage", image_url, err);
    return false; // resolve with "false" for failure
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Version using old `fs` package:

```js
const fs = require('fs')

const unlink = (file) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.unlink(file, (error) => {
        if (error) reject(error)
        resolve()
    })
})
```

Use as following:

```js
await unlink('data.json')
```

Answer (score -2):

The error will always go to catch block,

```
try {
  await this._userService.removeUserImage(user);
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err);
  throw new InternalServerErrorException(
    'Error occurred while trying to remove file.'
  );
}
```

Suggestion: You don't need to convert unlink(callback) to promise fs has promise function also, check [this](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_unlink_path)

```
const fs = require('fs');
const fsPromises = fs.promises;

public removeUserImage(
   user: User,
): Promise<void> {
   const pathToRemoveImage = 'src/public/uploads'+ '/' + user.image_url;
   return fsPromises.unlink(pathToRemoveImage);
 }
```

Comment: Did you literally just copy the first code block from my answer? Also, `unlink()` returns `Promise<void>`, not `Promise<NodeJS.ErrnoException | boolean>`